# react unit testing with jest debug

Tags: reactjs, debugging, jestjs

I am writing some unit tests for react using jest and it fails at one point.  I want to debug the unit tests and I try the following

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/troubleshooting.html

However on the first run itself

```
node --debug-brk ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

I get the following error

```
node_modules\.bin\jest:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of this:**

node --debug-brk ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand

**try this:**

node --debug-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand

(or)

node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  `"$0"` should be `'$0'`

Comment: This is something generated by the library I cannot change this.